# hide panel with commandbutton

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

i am using jsf and i am trying to show a hidden panel this what i tried

```xml
<h:commandButton update=":outPanel" actionListener="#{SelectBean.mod1()}" image="Ressources/images/update.png" style="vertical-align:middle" >
    Modifier
</h:commandButton>

<p:panel visible="#{SelectBean.bol}" closable="true" toggleable="true" id="outPanel" styleClass="outPanel" widgetVar="outpanel">
    <h:outputLabel value="Nom " />
    <h:inputText value="#{SelectBean.nom}" />
    <br/>
    <h:outputLabel value="Experience " />
    <h:inputText value="#{SelectBean.exp}" /> 
    <br/>
    <h:commandButton value="Modifier"/>
</p:panel>
```

my bean is

```
            private boolean bol=false;


            public boolean getBol() {
                return bol;
            }
            public void setBol(boolean bol) {
                this.bol = bol;
            }
            public String mod1()
            {
                bol = true;
                return "success";
            }
```

but this thing not working the panel is always hidden.

Comment: change visible to rendered

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, your panel will be shown if `bol` is **true**

```xml
<p:panel rendered="#{selectBean.bol}" closable="true"  toggleable="true"   id="outPanel" styleClass="outPanel" widgetVar="outpanel">
```

Also i think you have wrong syntax, you should call methods and variables of your class through `selectBean` but not `SelectBean`